# Is there a way to change the left alt key to be set as the spacebar?

Tags: windows, keyboard, key-binding

I tried a few regedit tools and keyboard editing programs, they mostly say that the alt key is not configurable. My spacebar is broken and making my alt key the spacebar seems like the easiest and cheapest solution. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this serious? What if you need the Alt key? A new keyboard costs 15 bucks.

Comment: Have you tried [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) or similar apps?

Comment: tried sharpKeys, didnt work.

Comment: also this is a laptop in response to @JanDoggen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) will do what you're looking to accomplish, assuming you run Windows, which given the mention of `regedit` seems likely. Once AutoHotkey is installed, save the following script in a file with the extension `.ahk`:

```
LAlt::Space
```

Then double-click the file. While the script is running, your left alt key will produce a space character, and you'll have a 'H' icon in your system tray by which you can exit the script, edit it, and otherwise control how it behaves.